# j2ee server setup and beginners tutorial

Tags: java

I've got basic to intermediate knowledge of java and would like to install a j2ee server on my debian machine. Can anyone tell me what I need or point me in the right direction to a good tutorial?

Thanks

--Mark

Comment: Asking for tutorials is generally not a good idea, as the tutorials get out of date quickly, and are of little use to future visitors. Instead, if you have a specific question about where you're stuck, feel free to [ask another question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask) outlining exactly where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might want to start with Glassfish.  Here's a good quickie tutorial on [how to install it on debian](http://www.stpe.se/2008/07/installing-glassfish-on-debian-etch-ubunt/).

Comment: do I need to run this in conjunction with tomcat or apache? Do you know any tutorials on creating your first j2ee aplication?

Comment: @Mark D - You might want to look into downloading the NetBeans development environment.  It will come with a number of pre-built examples that you can look at.